# MS Access: Create Ranking/ Priority & Show Highest Row

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I'm trying to create a database for my organization about our employees and the relevant licenses they hold for their job. There are 100s of jobs and licenses that I've bucketed into three buckets to try to align them: 1. General Employee, 2. Administration, 3. Services

However we have a few issues:

1. because licenses also have endorsements so someone who's considered a service person but has a "general employee" license can still be working in services (because we're going to assume they have an endorsement to work in services)
2. We don't want to delete users if their license and positions may not match up.
3. Educators can have more than one license in the same group/ bucket ass well

So I want to create a ranking/ priority for these relationships between license and positions (see below for ranking) and I want to create a query so that if a person has more than one license (thus producing more than one line), we can keep the top line whether it's a 1, 2 or 3 (by prioritizing 1s over 2s over 3s), and delete the bottom lines.

Perfect Match (Role - License):

- General - General = 1
- Services - Services  = 1
- Admin - Admmin = 1

Good Match:

- General - Services = 2
- Services - General = 2

Bad Match:

- General - Admin = 3
- Services - Admin = 3
- Admin - Services = 3
- Admin - General = 3

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would solve this by creating a uninoned sub query where I explicately state the value of each rank in each of the 3 sub queries. Then, I'd order the outer query by the rank field.

The below query groups all the 1's at the top, then 2's and 3's. Assuming you want to group by person first, you'd list whatever field could uniquely identify the person first in the order by. for example: "ORDER BY EmployerNo, Rank".

Also, If you don't want the rank field to appear in the output, just explicately state which fields to select in the outer query instead of the "SELECT *" I'm using below.

```
SELECT * 
FROM(
    SELECT 1 as rank, * 
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE (Role = "General" and License = "General")
    OR (Role = "Services" and License = "Services")
    OR (Role = "Admin" and License = "Admin")
    UNION
    SELECT 2 as rank, * 
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE (Role = "General" and License = "Services")
    OR (Role = "Services" and License = "General")
    UNION
    SELECT 3 as rank, * 
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE (Role = "General" and License = "Admin")
    OR (Role = "Services" and License = "Admin")
    OR (Role = "Admin" and License = "Services")
    OR (Role = "Admin" and License = "General")
) as a
ORDER BY Rank
```

Edit: Adding a requested variation to only report the highest ranked record for each employee and license. So, I'm joining the query from earlier to itself with some a small change. The change is to make the query an aggregate query where were reporting only the the max rank for each license and employee. (I'm guessing at the name of the employee field). When we inner join these queries, we'll report all the fields from the original query that that match the MaxRank, license# and employee#.

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM(
    SELECT 1 as rank, * 
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE (Role = "General" and License = "General")
    OR (Role = "Services" and License = "Services")
    OR (Role = "Admin" and License = "Admin")
    UNION
    SELECT 2 as rank, * 
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE (Role = "General" and License = "Services")
    OR (Role = "Services" and License = "General")
    UNION
    SELECT 3 as rank, * 
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE (Role = "General" and License = "Admin")
    OR (Role = "Services" and License = "Admin")
    OR (Role = "Admin" and License = "Services")
    OR (Role = "Admin" and License = "General")
) as a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Min(rank) as maxrank, License, employee 
    FROM(
        SELECT 1 as rank, * 
        FROM YourTable
        WHERE (Role = "General" and License = "General")
        OR (Role = "Services" and License = "Services")
        OR (Role = "Admin" and License = "Admin")
        UNION
        SELECT 2 as rank, * 
        FROM YourTable
        WHERE (Role = "General" and License = "Services")
        OR (Role = "Services" and License = "General")
        UNION
        SELECT 3 as rank, * 
        FROM YourTable
        WHERE (Role = "General" and License = "Admin")
        OR (Role = "Services" and License = "Admin")
        OR (Role = "Admin" and License = "Services")
        OR (Role = "Admin" and License = "General")
    ) as a
    GROUP BY License, employee 
) as b on a.rank = b.maxrank and a.License = b.License and a.employee = b.employee
ORDER BY Rank
```

Edit #2: changed max to min

Comment: @GordonLinoff - looks ok to me... what am I missing?

Comment: I created a test Access DB in Access2007 with no problem.

Comment: It works. This is awesome. Is there anyway to add to this query to remove any lower duplicates (by their license # or employee #)?

Comment: @PJS, so if there is a rank 2 record and a rank 3 record that both have the same Licence# and Employee#, you want to return only the rank 3 record?

Comment: @Chance If john is a general employee and he has two general license (rank 1s), as well as rank 2 and rank 3 record, I want to make sure his rank 1 is the only one that shows. Likewise, if his highest ranking is 2 but he hass a 3, I want the 3 to be deleted.

Comment: @PJS Just change the Max function to a Min function. :)